# Laravel custom validation - get parameters

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to get the parameter passed in the validation rule.

For certain validation rules that I have created, I'm able to get the parameter from the validation rule, but for few rules it's not getting the parameters.

In model I'm using the following code:

```
public static $rules_sponsor_event_check = array(
    'sponsor_id' => 'required',
    'event_id' => 'required|event_sponsor:sponsor_id'
);
```

In ValidatorServiceProvider I'm using the following code:

```
    Validator::extend('event_sponsor', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $sponsor_id = Input::get($parameters[0]);
        $event_sponsor = EventSponsor::whereIdAndEventId($sponsor_id, $value)->count();

        if ($event_sponsor == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But here I'm not able to get the sponsor id using the following:

```
$sponsor_id = Input::get($parameters[0]);
```

Comment: Try `dd($parameters[0])` to check if the parameter is passed correctly.

Comment: dd($parameters[0])  is displaying - "sponsor_id"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a 4th the whole validator is passed to the closure you define with `extends`. You can use that to get the all data which is validated:

```
Validator::extend('event_sponsor', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $sponsor_id = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], null);
    // ...
});
```

By the way I'm using `array_get` here to avoid any errors if the passed input name doesn't exist.

Comment: I used like the following but it is returning null - $sponsor_id = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], null);
            dd($sponsor_id); - do I need to pass the $validator to the following - $validator = Validator::make($input, EventSponsor::$rules_sponsor_event_check);

Comment: Please check what `$validator->getData()` actually returns

Comment: @lukasgeiter how do I set/access ":other" in the validation message?

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

> The custom validator Closure receives three arguments: the name of the
>   $attribute being validated, the $value of the attribute, and an array
>   of $parameters passed to the rule.

Why `Input::get( $parameters );` then? you should check $parameters contents.

Edit. 
Ok I figured out what are you trying to do. You are not going to read anything from input if the value you are trying to get is not being submitted. Take a look to

```
dd(Input::all());
```

You then will find that

```
sponsor_id=Input::get($parameters[0]);
```

is working in places where sponsor_id was submited.

Comment: The parameters hold the name of another input parameter. The OP wants to get the value of that.

Comment: $input = Input::get( $parameters );dd($input); is throwing an Exception  - ErrorException in Arr.php line 219:
Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: For dd(Input::all()); is displaying an empty array. I also have tried passing the parameter a dummy value like this - 'event_id' => 'required|event_sponsor:123' and it is also displaying an empty array.

Comment: Input will read stuff submited to your request. That's what Input does

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I have code like this in the controller, where I'm assigning values to the $input variable and passing to the validator - $input = array();
        $user = $auth->toUser();
        $input['event_id'] = $eventId;//event id for event validation
        $input['sponsor_id'] = $sponsorId; //event id for sponsor validation
        $input['organizer_id'] = $user->id;

    
            $validator = Validator::make($input, EventSponsor::$rules_sponsor_event_check);